# Configure HTTPS for localhost to gain access to microphone on phone via USB

Tags: webpack, https, progressive-web-apps, microphone, self-signed-certificate

I'm setting up my dev environment using [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa) template.
My goal is to gain access to the microphone, so I can start developing a small project using the Web Audio API. I run the server on Windows 7 laptop and accessing it locally is working fine -> I open localhost, call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia and gain access to the stream.
However, I want to run it on my phone (Nokia 6 with Android 9).
But to access the microphone there, my localhost needs HTTPS and I can't get the Windows 7 trust my generated certificate. (Or at least Chrome says so. Tested on Opera too.)

I set up my server to use https and the generated certificate by modifying some configurations of the webpack express server (hopefully the right way)
In /build/dev-server.js I have (besides all other logic in the template):

```
const app = express()
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../cert/server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../cert/server.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../cert/rootCA.pem'))
}
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port)
```

I pass the webpack validation and the server runs successfully, but the browser still says NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, even though I provide SAN (at least I think I do)
I generate a certificate using OpenSSL by following [this](https://medium.com/@tbusser/creating-a-browser-trusted-self-signed-ssl-certificate-2709ce43fd15) article.
The difference here is that the article gives an example of an IIS server certificate configuration (through mmc.exe) and my application is just a webpack express server, ran locally. So I do both of what the article suggests in the same place -> under personal certificates I add both rootCA.pem and server.pfx. Under Trusted Root Certification Authorities I imported rootCA.pem but didn't get a warning message as the article said.

That didn't work.

I had trouble generating certificate with other tools. Could not generate with makecert.exe (didn't try harder, because it's deprecated) and New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet is not available in Windows 7 Powershell.

Could you help me find what I'm doing wrong? Am I configuring webpack correctly and if yes - what is the right way to trust my self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://localhost for these APIs without HTTPS. It is done that way so you can develop applications easier.

I have used several of these APIs for different projects. I have also used USB and BlueTooth.

Now accessing from an external device will require real HTTPS.

For me it is easier to test from devices by deploying to a test origin. I use S3 and CloudFront if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will definitely check it out. By real HTTPS you mean purchase a CA signed certificate, right? Self-signed won't work?

Comment: well TLS certificates are free these days. The reason I use AWS CloudFront and their certificate mgt service is they are free, easy to provision and take about 10 seconds for me to make active.
LetsEncrypt is a took for free certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this post and is trying to achieve something similar - go checkout ngrok - on Linux, just download the snap, run your localhost server on specific port, then in the terminal, where ngrok is located enter './ngrok http {your localhost port}' and you're live with https enabled. It works great for development purposes. Happy coding! :)